# MongoDB Aggregate - Unwind, group and project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Using the collection `Users`, is it possible to retrieve the below unique list of organisations/owners? If this current set up isn't possible, is it possible to get the same results from two ID-linked collections with one query?

Currently, using Mongoose I can only retrieve the group of organisation names:

**Current query**

`userModel.aggregate([
      { $unwind:'$organisations' }
    , { $group: { name: '$organisations.name' } }
    ])`

---

**Users**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53f4a94e7c88310000000001"), 
  "email" : "bob@example.com",
  "organisations" : [
    {
      "name" : "OrgOne", 
      "isOwner" : true
    }
  ]
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53f4a94e7c88310000000002"), 
  "email" : "ash@something.com",
  "organisations" : [
    {
      "name" : "OrgOne"
    }
  ]
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53f4a94e7c88310000000003"), 
  "email" : "george@hello.com",
  "organisations" : [
    {
      "name" : "OrgTwo", 
      "isOwner" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Results**

```
{ "orgName" : "OrgOne", 
  "owner" : 53f4a94e7c88310000000001
},
{ "orgName" : "OrgTwo", 
  "owner" : 53f4a94e7c88310000000003
}
```

Thanks in advance, Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an odd use of aggregation to me, but possibly there are several "organisations" per user here, so I guess I'll continue:

```js
userModel.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "organisations.isOwner": true } },
        { "$unwind": "$organisations" },
        { "$match": { "organisations.isOwner": true } },
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$organisations.name",
            "owner": { "$first": "$_id" }
        }} 
    ],
    function(err,result) {

    }
);
```

If there is more than one owner and you need some precedence then you can implement a **`$sort`** before the group. Or otherwise just **`$project`** rather than group in order to get everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this appears to return an empty result. Any ideas?

Comment: If it would make it simpler to only have one organisation per user, then that is a definite consideration.

Comment: @NickPrice Typo "organizations" been talking american all day

Comment: Really appreciated. Haven't used the `$first` operator before. Many thanks!